# How to Map the data that I am getting from ajax React js?

Tags: javascript, ajax, reactjs

I am new to react js. How to map through the data I am getting json response from ajax.I know i did wrong some place But i don't know where.This the error I am getting

> Uncaught TypeError: this.state.data.map is not a function

[image]
This is My code

```
/**
 * Created by arfo on 6/26/2016.
 */
var React =require('react');
var api = require('../utils');


var Bulkmail = React.createClass({
    getInitialState:function () {
      return{
          default:10,
          data:'',
          color:'#58FA58'

      }
    },
    componentDidMount:function () {
        api.getemail(this.state.default).then(function (response) {
           this.setState({
               data:response

           })
        }.bind(this))
    },
    onSubmit:function (e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      console.log(this.refs.text.value.trim());


    },

    onChange:function (e) {
     e.preventDefault();
        //console.log(this.refs.text.value.trim())
        var data = this.refs.text.value.trim();
        if(isNaN(data)){
            this.setState({
                color:'#FE2E2E'
            })
        }else{
            this.setState({
                color:'#58FA58'
            })
        }
    },
    render:function () {
        console.log(this.state.data);
        var results = this.state.data;
        return(
           <div className="bodybox">
               <div className="box">
                  <div className="upc">
                      <p>Generate Bulk Email</p>
                      <form onSubmit={this.onSubmit}>
                      <input onChange={this.onChange} type="text" style={{border:'1px solid '+this.state.color}}  ref="text" defaultValue={this.state.default} placeholder="Enter Number"/>
                       <button>Get Data</button>
                      </form>
                      <div className="result">
                          <ul>
                               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
                              {this.state.data.map(function (data) {
                                  return  <li>data.email</li>
                              })}
                             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

                          </ul>
                      </div>

                  </div>
                   <div className="tdown">

                       <p>Json Format</p>


                       <textarea  defaultValue={"json"} />
                   </div>
               </div>
           </div>
        )
    }
});

module.exports = Bulkmail ;
```

Answer (score 3):

set **data:[ ]** in

```
getInitialState:function () {
      return{
          default:10,
          data:[],
          color:'#58FA58'

      }
    },
```

and check

```
componentDidMount:function () {
    api.getemail(this.state.default).then(function (response) {

    console.log('CHECK',response) //   <----------------

       this.setState({
           data:response

       })
    }.bind(this))
},
```

Answer (score 1):

Your state data is not defined as an array. Correct it as:

```
getInitialState:function () {

  return{
      default:10,
      data: [],
      color:'#58FA58'

  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Add 

getInitialState: function() {
     return{
      default:10,
      data:[],
      color:'#58FA58'

  }
}
```